# Proof that the inverse of a nonsingular lower triangular matrix is also lower triangular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lu-decomposition

Is anyone able to construct an easy-to-follow proof that the inverse of a nonsingular lower triangular matrix is also lower triangular? I have been attempting to construct a proof by contradiction to no avail. Is this the right way to go about it? If not, could someone show a way to prove it?